# Javascript adding array to table with borders

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add some random data to a table with borders. I looked for some tutorials but could not manage to do it. Program asks user for name of a couple of countries, then I store them as array. But when I run it, it displays as 'country1country2' for example and without borders. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
    <script>
       var n,count=[],limit=10;
       ncheck();
       function ncheck() {
         if (! Number ( n ) || n > limit || n < 1) {
           n =  +prompt("Please enter the number of countries", "Enter");
           ncheck();
         }
         while ( n > 0) {

           count.push (  prompt( n +" more countries left", "Enter" ) );
           --n;
         }
      } 
      for(var i = 0; i<count.length; i++)
      {
        document.write('<tr><td>'+ count[i] + '</td></tr>');
      }

      document.write('</table>');

     </script>
   </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script><script type="text/javascript">` ORLY?

Comment: Ohh, no. Every time you write code like this Douglas Crockford kills a kitten.

Comment: Well it was a copy paste mistake, wow calm down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to style tables.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vk95062a/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having

```
<script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

you should just have a single tag --> `<script> </script>` not two